# Translate ES6 'for' loop from ES5 'for-each' loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I need help with translating the following es6 loop to es5 code.

```
for (let [field_name, field] of impList) {
//// some code
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: That depends a lot on what `impList` is. A `Map`? An array?

Comment: Have you tried using a transpiler? [Use Babel](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=on&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&playground=true&code=for%20(let%20%5Bfield_name%2C%20field%5D%20of%20impList)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%2F%2F%20some%20code%0D%0A%7D).

Answer (score 8):

Assuming that `impList` is an `Array` (or an array-like object), and not an ES6 [Iterable type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#iterable) (which would require polyfills, etc), you can roughly translate that to a `for` loop:

```
for (var i=0; i<impList.length; i++) {
    var field_name = impList[i][0];
    var field = impList[i][1];
}
```

Or a [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
impList.forEach(function(entry) {
    var field_name = entry[0];
    var field = entry[1];
});
```

In addition to `impList` possibly being an Iterable, there are some nuances here that I didn't translate to ES5, because there are quite a lot of caveats. Which is why you should be using a transpiler such as [Babel](http://babeljs.io).

Comment: to be honest, I dont understand Babel's code:                                            for (var _iterator = impList.entries()[Symbol.iterator](), _step; !(_iteratorNormalCompletion = (_step = _iterator.next()).done); _iteratorNormalCompletion = true) {
                     var _step$value = _slicedToArray(_step.value, 2);
                            var field_name = _step$value[0];
                     var _field = _step$value[1]; }

Comment: Babel's output is written for computers, not humans :) It includes polyfills, shims & functionality to address the nuances I described above. All you need to know is you put in ES6 and it outputs valid ES5!

Comment: When I put the es5 code, I get error on 'Symbol' object.

Comment: My project is in ES5. I am refactoring ES6 to ES5. Do I need to include it to write ES5?